# Example of non-path-connected closed set

Tags: general-topology

I learned that an open subset of $\mathbb R$ with normal Euclidean Topology is path connected iff it is connected.

Then, I wonder what would happen if it's a closed subset. The same holds for any closed sets? or is there a counterexample?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a closed set that is connected but not path-connected, then I suspect the most usual example is the "topologist's sine curve":
$$
\left\{(x,y) : y = \sin \left( \frac 1 x \right) \text{ or }( x=0\ \&\ -1\le y\le 1)\right\}.
$$
This is the closure in $\mathbb R^2$ of the graph of $y=\sin\left(\dfrac 1 x \right).$

Answer (score 2):

The only connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the intervals. And each interval is convex, hence is path connected. So for any $E\subset \mathbb R,$ $E$ is connected iff $E$ is path connected.

Answer (score 1):

The [Topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) is a classic example of a closed subset of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is connected but not path-connected, so for closed sets the notions *are* quite  different.